# Select case result of a select statement (check multiple rows for condition)

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query here, basically I want to check the rows for a combination of parameters to have each person logged on a project only once. I want to check for the id/info combo and return either the id or a 0 for new entry. The query here returns nil, but I'd like to return 0 if no results found. I can check all rows using case or IF statements, but I just can't get the query right to select based on the results from all rows. Thanks!

```
SELECT id FROM project_team WHERE name = ? AND project_id = ?
```

Comment: give some sample data, expected output and what is your current query returning ?

Comment: @vhu thanks, just what I needed.. I was trying If Not Null, Ifs .. couldn't find that one!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **IFNULL()** function:

```
SELECT IFNULL(id, '0') FROM project_team WHERE name = ? AND project_id = ?
```

Or possibly:

```
SELECT(IFNULL((SELECT id FROM project_team WHERE name = ? AND project_id = ?), 0))
```

Comment: iffnul  is not mysql

Answer (score 2):

Use [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SELECT id 
              FROM project_team 
              WHERE name = ? 
                AND project_id = ?, 0)
```